# Are there instructions anywhere to assist with installing PostGIS 3.0.0 on CentOS 8.1?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, centos8, postgis-installation

Is there an end to end guide of installing PostGIS 3.0.0 on a fresh install of PostgreSQL on CentOS 8.1?

I have a .sql file with this line:
`CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

I login as a postgres database user I created after installation: `pgdev` that I then used to create a database: `db_pgdev` where I want PostGIS installed,

I get this error when I execute: **`CREATE EXTENSION postgis`**

```
psql:./install-postgis.sql:4: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

---

Indeed there is no such file when I check:

These are the only files in:  `/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/`

```
plpgsql--1.0.sql
plpgsql.control
plpgsql--unpackaged--1.0.sql
```

The directory:
`/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/` is owned by OS user `root`.

---

```
sql>select version();`

PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4), 64-bit
```

---

OS installed was: **CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911** (Core)

(not sure why it says: Red Hat 8.3.1-4 in: `select version();`)

---

On the PostGIS site, there are no instructions to install anything like `dnf install <pkg>`.

I simply starts with SQL statements to enable PostGIS, as if it is already there and simply needs an extension created.

Are there instructions missing there? or something that needs to be done before `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` ?

---

When I run:
`#dnf install postgis30_12`

**I get this error:**

```
Error: Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job 
- nothing provides hdf5 needed by postgis30_12-3.0.1-2.rhel8.x86_64 
- nothing provides xerces-c needed by postgis30_12-3.0.1-2.rhel8.x86_64

(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages) –
```

This does not seem stable (or packaged correctly) to install if the most suitable dependencies cannot be found.

I'm having little confidence in this path, there must be something missing.

---

Before I run the `dnf` command, I have the latest pgdg-redhat-repo-latest installed:

```
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: So, did you  install the PostGIS rpm through yum [as explained on their homepage](https://postgis.net/install/)

Comment: I'm not using yum, but rather dnf.  I updated the original post (see the very end) to show that PostGIS30_12* seems to be on the system already (3.0.1-2.rhel8), however it got there, I don't know.  I did not execute any command to install postgis, it must have come with the installation of Postgres 12.x during that process.  Thank you.

Comment: In the section titled: 'Red Hat / Centos / Scientific Linux', I'm not sure what that is saying.  I cannot translate that to english or exactly what needs to be done, or even if I need to do it.  It does not indicate that I need to do anything there, or how to determine if I need to do anything.  Nothing there refers to:  PostGIS 3.x.x so I am at a dead end.  I'm not sure why the documentation there refers to anything but the latest production release.

Comment: I don't use `dnf`, but according to the man page, you need `dnf list --installed` to list the currently **installed** packages, `dnf list`  only shows *available* packages, so you should run `dnf install postgis30_12` to install the package

Comment: OK, that seems like the right direction.

When I run:

#dnf install postgis30_12

I get:

Error:
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides hdf5 needed by postgis30_12-3.0.1-2.rhel8.x86_64
  - nothing provides xerces-c needed by postgis30_12-3.0.1-2.rhel8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Comment: solution described by @a_horse_with_no_name solved my problem . In my case on CentOS 7 and PostgreSQL: `dnf install postgis25_12`